# SQL*Loader-128: unable to begin a session

Tags: oracle, unix, sql-loader

I'm trying to use SQL Loader to load data in my table from a csv file.

<---load.sh-->

```
ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/OraHome11g
export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=/oracle/OraHome11g/bin
export PATH
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start
sqlldr RETAIL_FIN/RETAIL_FIN$123@ERDEV control=LBR.ctl
```

<---load.ctl-->

```
  load data
    infile '/home/tclfin/LBR.ctl'
    into table LOAN_BALANCE_MASTER_INT
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    (ACCOUNT_NO,CUSTOMER_NAME,LIMIT)
```

After executing the script i'm getting the following error :

```
LSNRCTL for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 27-MAY-2016 16:14:34

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Fri May 27 16:14:34 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-128: unable to begin a session
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $ in your password is being seen as an environment variable reference, or in this case `$1` as the first argument to the script - which is probably null. The password actually being used passed to Oracle is `RETAIL_FIN23`, not `RETAIL_FIN$123`.

Your script needs to escape the $ sign:

```
sqlldr RETAIL_FIN/RETAIL_FIN\$123@ERDEV control=LBR.ctl
```

You can see the same effect quite simply:

```
$ echo sqlldr RETAIL_FIN/RETAIL_FIN$123@ERDEV control=LBR.ctl
sqlldr RETAIL_FIN/RETAIL_FIN23@ERDEV control=LBR.ctl
$ echo sqlldr RETAIL_FIN/RETAIL_FIN\$123@ERDEV control=LBR.ctl
sqlldr RETAIL_FIN/RETAIL_FIN$123@ERDEV control=LBR.ctl
```